# F# infix operators in c#?

Tags: c#, f#, infix-operator

In F# it is not uncommon to declare infix operators for binary operators. But how are they represented if we try to use them in C# Since there are no way of declaring infix operators in C#?

Toy Example

```
let ( .|. ) a b = a + b
```

Comment: You can’t define new operators in C#, only redefine existing ones like +, -, *, /, <, <<, >>, >, |, &, %, ==, !=, <=, =>.

Comment: It's worth noting that after a few years of people creating just about any infix operator imaginable, it's now considered poor style to do so without reason. You won't be able to tell what the code is doing when two or more libraries all use the same infix operators

Answer (score 9):

If you check the IL representation of your operator, you will see this:

```
 .method public static specialname int32
    op_DotBarDot(
      int32 a,
      int32 b
    ) cil managed
```

Unfortunately you won't be able to refer to this from `C#`. However you can add an attribute:

```
[<CompiledName("addop")>]
let ( .|. ) a b = a + b
```

Then you can just reference your F# dll from C# and call it via `addop`:

`Console.WriteLine(global::Program.addop(1,2));`

> 3
>
> Process finished with exit code 0.

Comment: thanks. I ended up just trying to see it in a toy project, and you can refer to it, but the name for -+- barplusbar or something simular. which are pointless.